# PowerShell {% if %} {% endif %} syntax throws an error

Tags: powershell, ansible, yaml, win-shell

I wrote this PowerShell script:

```
- name: Some name
  win_shell: |
    [xml]$myFile = Get-Content "C:\MyFile.xml"
    $myFile.SelectSingleNode("//some-element").InnerText = "new text"
    {% if 1 -eq 1 %}
    $myFile.SelectSingleNode("//another-element").InnerText = "new text"
    {% endif %}
    $myFile.Save("C:\MyFile.xml")
```

and I am getting this error:

```
"template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block'"
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Can someone please help?

Comment: This is ansible, right?

Comment: Yes. It is ansible task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is Jinja2 Templating. The compare statement need to be in Jinja2 syntax, `{% if 1 == 1 %}` instead of Shell syntax. This is because the templating will be done on the Control Node in Python and before sending over the Shell commands to the Windows Remote Node.

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to specify IF ELSE statements in Ansible Jinja2 Templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66007751/6771046)
- [Ansible Jinja2 Template IF statement](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4138/)

**Documentation**

- [Jinja2 Template Designer Documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the "-eq" of the if statement
I replace it by == and it works for me